# AEM 6.5 Oracle DB NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: security, aem, oracle19c, oracle-wallet

from my AEM 6.5 instance currently I connect correctly to an oracle db using tcp:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=my-oracle-db)(PORT=1531)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MY_SRV)))
```

But when I try to establish a secure connection like this:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCPS)(HOST=my-oracle-secure-db)(PORT=1541)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=MY_SRV)))
```

I get a `oraclepki.jar must be in the classpath: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/security/pki/OracleWallet`. The wallet is configured correctly and I tried to add the following dependency in my project, without any result:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
        <version>19.3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
...
    <embedded>
        <groupId>com.oracle.ojdbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>oraclepki</artifactId>
        <target>/apps/myproject/install</target>
    </embedded>
...
    <filter root="/apps/myproject/install/oraclepki-19.3.0.0.jar"/>
```

Do you have any idea of the cause?

Regards

Comment: If you go to http://localhost:4502/system/console/bundles do you see the Oracle PKI bundle? Is it active?

Comment: Now, is present and active but I received the same error